# An abstract representation for $\operatorname{PSL}_2(F)$

Tags: group-theory

Let $F$ be a field, how can I determine the structure of $\operatorname{PSL}_2(F)$ without using matrices or quotient groups? I mean a comletely abstract way.

(For example, I know $\Bbb Z(p^\infty)\cong \left<a_1,a_2,a_3,... \mid (\forall n\in \Bbb N)(a_n=a_{n+1}^p)\right>$  which is an abstract representation of $\Bbb Z(p^\infty)$)

Comment: Representation or presentation?

Comment: whichever is closer in meaning to *determining the structure* in a matrix-free, equivalence-class-free way.

Comment: @Seirios Some people make a distinction between a *representation* and a *linear representation*. The former is sometimes called a *realisation*. For example, $\langle a, b, c, d;[a, b][c, d]\rangle$ can be realised as the fundamental group of a [large costa mug](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/91/Cup_of_Costa_Coffee.jpg/320px-Cup_of_Costa_Coffee.jpg).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The groups $\operatorname{PSL}(2,F)$ and $\operatorname{PGL}(2,F)$ are automorphisms of a certain geometry. The geometry can be described in an entirely internal way, but probably you'll prefer the external method:

Let $$\operatorname{PGL}(2,F) = \left\{ z \mapsto \frac{\alpha z + \beta}{\gamma z + \delta} : \alpha\delta-\beta\gamma \neq 0; \alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta \in F \right\}$$
and $$\operatorname{PSL}(2,F) = \left\{ z \mapsto \frac{\alpha z + \beta}{\gamma z + \delta} : \alpha\delta-\beta\gamma = 1; \alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta \in F \right\}$$

These are called [Möbius transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) or linear fractional substitutions. These were some of the earliest permutation groups studied, so have a huge associated theory (see sections 1-17 of the wikipedia article for a brief overview that leaves out quite a lot of interesting things).

For example, $\operatorname{PSL}(2,R)$ is (defined to be) the automorphism group of the real projective line (restricting its action on the Riemann sphere to a line at infinity), and is (honestly) the automorphism group of the upper half plane model of hyperbolic geometry. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSL2(R)#M.C3.B6bius_transformations) for some more brief overview).

Answer (score 3):

For finite fields $F=\mathbb{F}_q$, with $q$ odd, there is the presentation of J.G. Sunday, Can. J. Math., Vol. XXIV, No. 6, 1972, pp. 1129-1131, namely
$$
PSL(2,F)=\langle S,T \mid S^q=1, T^2=(ST)^3, (S^{\frac{q+1}{2}}TS^4T)^2=1\rangle.
$$

Comment: I'm interested in the fields $\Bbb Q$, $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$.